# Jquery Insert Element, then do css Animation via Class Change - does not work

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I want to insert an element via "insertAfter". Afterwards I want to add a Class, to trigger a css animation.

When Im doing this with a Time Out it works:

**First Method (with Timeout)**

```
$content.insertAfter($("#2"));
setTimeout(function(){
    $content.addClass("blue"); 
}, 100);
```

But it does not work when I'm adding the Class directly after inserting the element:

**Second Method (without Timeout)**

```
$content.insertAfter($("#2")).addClass("blue");
```

Is there another solution? I dont want to use a Time Out Function.

I have made a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/b2eybnoy/

Comment: You should add element with class `red`, than to change it to `blue`. There is no animation, cause element is already blue... Think this question will self-destruct in 5 seconds...

Comment: Check out Fiddle, this is exactly what im doing!

Comment: color animation is working but. it not showing because there is no time gap to show effect.

Comment: Why do i need a time gap? The Animation is done by css, so it uses his own timer. The Animation should trigger, when the class changed. I think the problem is, the second mehtod has no "Class Change", because when he adds the class the element is not already inserted in the document. Or?

Comment: You need to force browser to render your new element, check answers below.

Comment: because it's too fast, when you insert it, it has no time to even be styled in the page before new class is added.

Comment: one more thing, number is not a legal character for starting an ID, you should use letter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the css transition is based on a rendered style being changed.

At the very instant when you insert the newly created element, it did not have time to be rendered by the browser. If you change the class in the very first command, it will not render the transition.

Alternativelly to `setTimeout`, you can use some techniques to force the browser to visually render the element's styles, like calling a visual property:

[**Updated JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/b2eybnoy/5/)

```
$("#2").click(function(){
    var $content = $("<div class='red'></div>");
    $content.insertAfter($("#2"));
    $content.offset();
    $content.addClass("blue");
});
```

Comment: You can also insert hidden div, than show it - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b2eybnoy/7/), that will also force rendering.

Comment: Nice, that works. Thanks a lot. I was sure there is a solution, but i hoped there is somethink like 

$content.insertAfter($("#2")).waitUntilElementIsRendered().addClass("blue");

Is the solution offset() bad for the performance?

Comment: @Vieper - You're welcome. Not performance issue. You are just requesting a visual property, it would work with many others. It just forces the browser to render the element in this processing batch, instead of waiting to the end of it

Answer (score 0):

Adding content to DOM takes some time and I think it works asynchronously. That means adding class to the element is done before this element is actually appears in DOM. So it think no, you shoul use timeout anyway.

UPDATE
Found a better solution here https://timtaubert.de/blog/2012/09/css-transitions-for-dynamically-created-dom-elements/

Comment: Nice, thanks for the link. That should also work. Im using now .offset() to wait until element is rendered completely.

Comment: I think you can use any function retrieving some position for the element since it forces element to rerender.

Answer (score 0):

When you add the new div, make sure you hide it first, add the new class, and fade in the new div.

Check out the fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/schwietertj/mtxf6vx0/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#1").click(function(){
    var $content = $("<div class='red'></div>");
    $content.insertAfter($("#2"));
    setTimeout(function(){
        $content.addClass("blue"); 
    }, 100);
});
$("#2").click(function(){
    var $content = $("<div class='red'></div>");
    $content.insertAfter($("#2")).hide();
    $content.addClass("blue").fadeIn(500);
});
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is not what im searching for. I dont want to hide element and i dont want to use jquery animation "FadeIn". I want to do this totally with css animation.

Comment: I just realized you had the css animation in your code. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

That's not work because after append the div tag to your document, immediately you change the class name and CSS engine can't see this change to run animation.
To solve this problem you can use this code:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/b2eybnoy/9/)

```
$("#2").click(function(){
    var $content = $("<div class='red'></div>");
    $content.insertAfter($("#2")).show(function(){
        $content.addClass("blue");
    }) 
});
```

Comment: Nice, that also works. But I Dont like using jquery functions like show, because it also do some things I dont need. For example adding style attribute: "overflow: hidden". But anyway. Thank you!